# Why CodeRush Extract Partial View doesn't work?

Tags: refactoring, coderush

This is the feature to which I'm referring to.

Here you can see it's enabled:
[image]

But actually it doesn't work:

[image]

I've also Resharper and Web Essentials installed on my PC.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug.

Could you please file an issue in our Support Center (http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) and our support team will be very happy to explore this with you.